# cannot start worker in apache spark due to wrong java version

Tags: apache-spark, centos7

I saw a similar question, but didn't solve mine, hence posted...please help if you can..

I have 1 worker node and separate master in apache spark configuration. By start-all.sh, I see only worker ID in master, not on slave on web UI.

my /etc/hosts on master node:

```
10.0.0.6    master
10.0.0.20   slave01
```

on master:

```
ll /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 73 Jan 13 00:14 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-0.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

On my master /opt/spark/conf/spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='10.0.0.6'
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-0.el7_9.x86_64'
```

When I run start-all.sh, heres the output:

```
[sudip@master sbin]$ ./start-all.sh 
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sudip-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out
slave01: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sudip-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out
master: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sudip-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-master.out
```

On master:

```
[sudip@master sbin]$ cat /opt/spark/logs/spark-sudip-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out
/opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I don't have any idea where it gets the "java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64" as in the log from. Any idea where I am going wrong.

Update:
I deleted the log file and created again. Now, the log file for the slave is empty even when I run (start-all.sh or start-slaves.sh. I dont see the slave entry also in http://:8080

Thanks and Regards,
Sudip

Comment: Did you setup spark-env.sh with JAVA_HOME on the worker node?

Comment: @Salim yes, on the worker node JAVA_HOME  is set too

Comment: I had only jre installed on slave01, heard that might be causing issues, so removed it and installed openjdk version "1.8.0_275"...but still same problem

Comment: The slave01 log file says "/opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64//bin/java: No such file or directory" where does it get that particular version from? :( I just recently installed centos on it.